# Docker image failing to build on AWS EC2 linux but works when built on Windows and Mac

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ec2, node-sass, react-scripts

When I run `docker-compose build minexample` with the following 3 files on Mac or Windows, the image is built successfully. But when I try to do the same thing on a AWS Linux 2 EC2 instance, it fails when running `node-sass`'s  install script (see below).

After much trial and error over 2 days, I realized that the issue goes away if I lower `react-scripts` version to "3.0.0". That would also mean I need to lower `eslint` in my dev dependency (which I don't include in the minimal example) from 7.12.0 to 5.16.0.

I have a few questions:

1. How can the docker build succeed on Mac/Windows, yet fail on Linux? I thought containers were supposed to be an isolated environment yet somehow the host OS affected the outcome here.
2. How do I figure out which node package versions are in conflict? It took a lot of time via trial and error to figure out that lowering `react-script`'s version fixed (or hid) the problem.

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "minexample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-router": "5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  }
}
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.16.0-alpine AS build

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# cache dependencies
COPY ./package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  minexample:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: minexample
```

#### Error

```
> node-sass@4.12.0 install /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass 
> node scripts/install.js

The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'minexample' failed to build
```

Comment: `Successfully built 2954ad2931b6` and `Successfully tagged app_minexample:latest` - I tried to replicate your issue, but it all works on Amazon Linux 2 instance. Please double check your build procedure.

Comment: @Marcin You're right. Part of what's made this difficult to troubleshoot is that once the build fails, it sometimes causes subsequent builds to also fail until I restart the docker service using `sudo service docker stop`. I've updated `package.json`. And if for some reason that still passes, this is my full dependency list: https://pastebin.com/VZ5eVHgQ

And just in case it helps, versions: `Docker version 19.03.13-ce, build 4484c46`, `docker-compose version 1.28.4, build cabd5cfb`

Comment: So it works now? Sorry, not sure from your comment.

Comment: No it fails once I added the 2 extra dependencies to the original post (`react` and `react-dom`). But if that works for you, try the pastebin. If that also works, then maybe my docker versions are somehow incompatible.

Comment: It all works. There are no issues build your docker image with dependencies from pastebin using Amazon Linux 2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Which EC2 tier are you using? And if possible can you let me know your docker version? I've reproduced the failure on 3-4 different EC2 t2.micro instances so I'm trying to figure out what the difference is.

Comment: I will provide the details in the answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

I tried to replicate the issue, but in my tests, the docker image is **built successfully**.

Instance used, `t2.small` (have not tested using `t2.micro`).

**Amazon Linux 2:**

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

**Docker**

```
docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13-ce, build 4484c46
```

**docker-compose**

```
docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.28.4, build cabd5cfb
```

**build image**

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
a_minexample        latest              82968af21096        24 minutes ago      426MB
node                10.16.0-alpine      9dfa73010b19        20 months ago       75.3MB
```

Comment: Thanks for reproducing the steps. I just tried it on `t2.small` instead of `t2.micro` and it worked. I'm rather mystified at how this can be. I suppose it must have been a resource problem then. Might upgrade to `t2.small` (losing the free tier) or consider building the image elsewhere and pushing to ECR in the future.

Comment: I failed with t2.micro but succeeded with t2.small, too